# Select Query - Upto Previous Date Records is Not Working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4

Following Laravel Query I Write for to get Upto Previous Date Records that's not getting any Records. If I Remove Date query its get Many Records.

`$data['frmdate_submit']` format is `2017-05-24`.

How to Fix this Problem

```
$getpreviousbalance = Companyledger::where('transaction_date', '>', $data['frmdate_submit'])
                ->WhereIn('frm_ledger', $ledgerlist)
                ->where('company_id', $companyids)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereData` instead of `where` when you are checking with dates.

```
$getpreviousbalance=Companyledger::whereDate('transaction_date','>',$data['frmdate_submit'])->WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->where('company_id',$companyids)->get();
```

hope this will works.

Comment: Its Produce Empty Results @SK Jajoriya

Comment: You are trying to fetch all records upto $data['frmdate_submit'] date. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$getpreviousbalance = Companyledger::where('company_id', $companyids)
    ->whereIn('frm_ledger', $ledgerlist)
    ->where('transaction_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['frmdate_submit']))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Its Not Return any Rows @Sandeesh

Comment: Run `dd($data)` and post the result here.

Comment: array:5 [▼
  "frmdate" => "24 May, 2017"
  "frmdate_submit" => "2017-05-24"
  "todate" => "24 May, 2017"
  "todate_submit" => "2017-05-24"
  "_token" => "aOdfNyEr6WXRAngc5lHshVrOcHDlQYIUfqiKXGYw"
] @Sandeesh

Comment: @abithashal if you need only records upto the date your submitting then change `>` or `<`.

Comment: @abithashal can you clear on how you want to use the date and which data you want to fetch? All information before this date or all information after this date?